# How to assign duplicate Leads with same Owner

Tags: leads, duplicate-management

**Background**

Leads are created via `web-to-lead` which means website visitors can created multiple Leads within Salesforce.

Also, Leads are assigned using a round robin method.

**Ideal Outcome**

If someone creates multiple Leads, I would like Salesforce to ensure they end up with the same record owner, such that the person is not contacted twice.

Ideally, I'd like a trigger event when the match is found, such that I can assign the owner.

**Request**

Any thoughts on how I might do this?

Comment: you need to write a trigger to find the previously exists owner and assign the same owner to the newly created record

Answer (score 0):

Before insert we can check the owner email and check duplicate in leads , if finds then update the records from trigger.new array.